# Re-apply default element properties in class

Tags: less

LESS has [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-mixins) which make it easy to re-use properties from one class or ID ruleset in another. Is there a way to reference properties for an element (without class or ID) inside another ruleset?  I'd like to do something like:

```
// Defined in a base .less file somewhere
a {
    color: blue;
}

// Defined within a more specific file
.myClass a {
    color: red;
}

// #myElement is used within .myClass, but I'd like to re-use the
// base styles.
#myElement a {
    a();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*:extend()` pseudo-class for that:

```
#myElement a {
    background: green;
    &:extend(a);
}
```

See: [Extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature)